# Using sprintf formatted string inside lldb expression

Tags: python, lldb

I need to run an lldb extression that will build a string in the runtime from the data it receives from API calls. Something like:

```
char buf[128];
cnt = ...//some API call goes here
addr = .../another API call goes here
sprintf(buf, "%s/%d_%p.dat", dirName, cnt, (const void*)addr);
```

The arguments are not known to me in Python. When I pass this to EvaluateExpression I get an error

> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Comment: The "TypeError" is a Python error, so you'll have to show us the Python code you are using to build this expression for us to tell what the error is.

Comment: While I agree with Jim, I suspect that you're not escaping your % - in Python, % is a placeholder for string formatting (https://pyformat.info)